# Baseline removal for multiple columns

Tags: python, baseline, spectral-python

I have a data frame with 300 rows and 666 columns. Each row is basically a spectrum. How to apply a Baseline removal package or any other method for an entire dataset?

Any suggestion related to the question would be great and appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: reduce 1 column please :D

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you.
Can you please elaborate on it?